# SWIFT - HKWorkout for non distance based workout

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm building an app to save pushup workouts. I need to create a HKWorkout variable, but all the constructors require distance. My workout doesn't include distance. What do I do with this variable? Are there other constructors?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can see, none of the HKWorkout constructors actually *require* distance—they all accept nil for that parameter—and the first one in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkout_Class/index.html) doesn't even take distance as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `nil` for the distance quantity if your workout doesn't include a distance traveled.

Answer (score -1):

You could try `HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)` when requesting HealthKit authorization. That's the closest current health kit definitions come, assuming you are going to have Apple Watch count the number of pushups.